# PHP - Help with string delimiters in echoing a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to build a HTML form if an item is in stock, but as I'm storing the html in a string variable using single quotes to delimit it, and then setting form attributes using double quotes inside the form, how then can I refer to a php variable inside the form to dynamically assign a value to 'addItem'. If you look at my code you'll see what I mean! I will echo the contents of $summary after this has been done, and $summary at this point contains information extracted from my SQL database about the product.

```
$summary .= '<form id="testbasket" method="GET" target="_parent" action="cattest.php" >
        <input type="text" id="addItem" name="addItem" value='.'"<?php echo $plantname; ?>"'.'>
        <input type="submit" value="Add To Basket" />
        </form>';
```

Note: I'm using _parent as the target because this sits inside an iframe in the parent page.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$summary .= '<form id="testbasket" method="GET" target="_parent" action="cattest.php" >
        <input type="text" id="addItem" name="addItem" value="' . $plantname . '" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add To Basket" />
        </form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation with `.` like so:

```
$summary .= '<form id="testbasket" method="GET" target="_parent" action="cattest.php" >
        <input type="text" id="addItem" name="addItem" value="'.$plantname.'">
        <input type="submit" value="Add To Basket" />
        </form>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it helped to iron out the errors I had with my concatenation to solve the problem and my page is working wonderfully now!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  print("<div id = \"someID\">" . $someVariable . "</div>");
?>
```

Comment: Or `print('<div id = "someID">' . $someVariable . '</div>');` We don't know the contents of `$plantname` but I don't think that this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but the code you have outputs the code as a string. You can simply concatenate the $plantname variable into the string. Here is your code using correct quotes:

```
$summary .= '<form id="testbasket" method="GET" target="_parent" action="cattest.php" >
    <input type="text" id="addItem" name="addItem" value="'.$plantname.'">
    <input type="submit" value="Add To Basket" />
    </form>';
```

You also only need to use the php open and close tags `<?php ?>` when you have explicitly already left a php section. Since what you're writing is still within php, you simply use the variable.

Comment: Thanks, its working now. I feel like I'm commenting the same kind of thing on many answers here but that's just because everyone was helpful and I appreciate your effort in providing me the same answer which has now worked and I am very grateful!